# Embedded Pig in Java : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run basic Embedded Pig Java code.

I am accessing the Hadoop Cluster from a remote machine.

HadoopVersion : `2.0.0-cdh4.3.0` , 
PigVersion    : `0.11.0-cdh4.3.0`

The code looks like this :

```
Properties lProperties = new Properties();
lProperties.setProperty("fs.defaultFS", "<server>:<hdfsport>");
lProperties.setProperty("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "<server>:<port>");
try {
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE,lProperties);
    pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '/input_data/pig_input.txt' as (key,name);");
    pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0 as id;");
    pigServer.store("B", "test_output");
}
```

I am able to run Pig Commands as well as Pig Scripts independently using PuTTy SSH.
However on running the above Java code in Eclipse IDE, I am getting the following error :

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Is it mandatory to have Cygwin installed to successfully run Embedded Pig in Java??

Answer (score 1):

For Pig version `0.11` Cygwin is a dependency. From version `0.12` on, Cygwin is not required anymore but you might still need to have some essential utilities such as `sed` and `gzip` installed.

See [PIG-2793 Make Pig Work on Windows without Cygwin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2793).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have noticed that the problem is only when I try to DUMP or STORE the result.It runs if these two operations are not part of the pig script.

Comment: I think that until you do DUMP or STORE, nothing really happens like with ordinary Pig scripts.

Comment: Instead of DUMP, if I do 'ILLUSTRATE B', then the output is correctly shown on the console. It means that the **input file is correctly read/loaded from HDFS.** The problem occurs only while trying to **write the result in HDFS**.

Comment: Good to know and good if that's enough for you. Have you tried with a newer version of Pig?